# two-level indexing in dataframes in pandas : count the number of second level index for each first level index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe pasted below with two-level indexing (first level is statename and second level is county name): 
[the image contains the statename and the counties in it in the second column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDwZf.png)

I need to count the number of counties in each state. (In the image pasted i have just information for a single state but the entire dataframe consists of several such similar entries for states and corresponding county names.) 
for ex. in the above pic it should return 5 for Alabama (i know there are 60 other counties within alabama but i have just pasted a small part of the bigger dataframe). 
Which pandas function can be used to return the counties count for each state?
I am a novice to pandas and just in the learning stage.

thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You should have posted a sample DataFrame object similar to your dataframe.

Comment: the hyperlink in the question shows a image of a part of my dataframe structure required to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate by [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(level=0).size()
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.groupby('STNAME').size()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'STNAME':['AL'] * 3 + ['MI'] * 4, 
                   'CTYNAME':list('abcdefg'),
                   'COL': range(7) }).set_index(['STNAME','CTYNAME'])
print (df)
                COL
STNAME CTYNAME     
AL     a          0
       b          1
       c          2
MI     d          3
       e          4
       f          5
       g          6

df1 = df.groupby(level=0).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
  STNAME  count
0     AL      3
1     MI      4

df1 = df.groupby('STNAME').size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
  STNAME  count
0     AL      3
1     MI      4
```

Answer (score 0):

it will give count for each `st_name` . i experimented with small list

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'st_name': 'alabama', 'cityname': [['alabama'], ['autuguva','county'],['county']]})

df.groupby('st_name').count()
```

Comment: Better is `size`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pandas/1822/grouping-data/6874/aggregating-by-size-and-count#t=201705300840165643736)